# Dockerfile not able to match Nodejs and NPM versions

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile where I am trying to install nodejs and npm to use when executing a setup.py file. However, I have not been able to sync nodejs and npm, causing an error when the setup.py file is run. How can I update nodejs so that npm can interact with it?

Here is the error:

```
#19 2.669 ERROR: npm v9.6.0 is known not to run on Node.js v12.22.12. You'll need to
#19 2.669 upgrade to a newer Node.js version in order to use this version of npm. This
#19 2.669 version of npm supports the following node versions: `^14.17.0 || ^16.13.0 ||
#19 2.669 >=18.0.0`. You can find the latest version at https://nodejs.org/.
```

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM debian:bullseye
ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
ENV CONDA_DIR /opt/conda

# Core installs
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade && \
    apt-get install -y git vim wget build-essential python3 ca-certificates bzip2 libsm6 libgl1-mesa-glx npm && \
    apt-get clean
    
RUN npm install -g npm@latest
    
RUN curl -fsSL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_19.x | bash - &&\
    apt-get install -y nodejs

RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3

# Install miniconda 
RUN echo 'export PATH=$CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH' > /etc/profile.d/conda.sh && \
    wget --quiet https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh && \
    /bin/bash ~/miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -p $CONDA_DIR && \
    rm -rf ~/miniconda3/miniconda3.sh && \
    $CONDA_DIR/bin/conda install --yes conda


# Create a user
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash neuroglancer_user
RUN chown -R neuroglancer_user:neuroglancer_user $CONDA_DIR

# Env vars
USER neuroglancer_user
ENV HOME /home/neuroglancer_user
ENV SHELL /bin/bash
ENV USER neuroglancer_user
ENV PATH $CONDA_DIR/bin:$PATH
WORKDIR $HOME

# setup the rest of the packages
RUN conda install --yes nose numpy pandas matplotlib scipy seaborn numba bokeh pillow ipython aiosignal \
anaconda-client \
anaconda-navigator \
anaconda-project \
asgiref \
asn1crypto \
astroid \
astropy \
Babel \
bitarray \
boto \
cachetools \
cffi \
chardet \
click \
cloudpickle \
clyent \
conda-build \
cudatoolkit \
cudnn \
Cython \
cytoolz \
dask \
dask-core \
dask-image \
datashape \
debugpy \
decorator \
dill \
distlib \
distributed \
Django \
docutils \
fastcache \
fasteners \
filelock \
Flask \
freetype-py \
frozenlist \
fsspec \
gevent \
gmpy2 \
google-auth \
greenlet \
grpcio \
hsluv \
h5py \
hdf5 \
imageio \
imagesize \
importlib-metadata \
incremental \
ipython \
isort \
itsdangerous \
jbig \
jeepney \
jsonschema \
jupyter \
jupyterlab \
keyring \
lazy-object-proxy \
locket \
lxml \
matplotlib \
mccabe \
more-itertools \
mpmath \
multipledispatch \
natsort \
navigator-updater \
nltk \
numba \
numpy \
numpydoc \
openpyxl \
pandas \
partd \
path.py \
pathlib2 \
patsy \
pep8 \
PIMS \
pip \
pkginfo \
platformdirs \
plotly \
pluggy \
ply \
protobuf \
psutil \
py \
pycodestyle \
pycosat \
pycrypto \
pycurl \
pydantic \
pylint \
pyodbc \
PyOpenGL \
PySocks \
pytest \
pytest-arraydiff \
pytest-astropy \
pytest-doctestplus \
pytest-openfiles \
pytest-remotedata \
PyWavelets \
QtAwesome \
qtconsole \
QtPy \
rope \
scikit-image \
scikit-learn \
scipy \
SecretStorage \
simplegeneric \
slicerator \
snowballstemmer \
sortedcontainers \
Sphinx \
sphinxcontrib-applehelp \
sphinxcontrib-devhelp \
sphinxcontrib-htmlhelp \
sphinxcontrib-jsmath \
sphinxcontrib-qthelp \
sphinxcontrib-serializinghtml \
spyder \
spyder-kernels \
SQLAlchemy \
statsmodels \
sympy \
testpath \
tifffile \
toolz \
traitlets \
Twisted \
typer \
unicodecsv \
virtualenv \
webencodings \
Werkzeug \
widgetsnbextension \
wrapt \
XlsxWriter \
xlwt \
zict \
zope.interface 
# Install Jupyter notebook to allow for more interactive neuroglancing
RUN conda install --yes -c conda-forge notebook \
    && conda clean -a
    
RUN pip install jupyterlab-pygments \
    docstring-parser \
    nibabel \
    webcolors \
    napari-plugin-engine \
    antspyx \
    napari-console \
    tables \
    pytomlpp \
    Pint \
    jupyter-console \
    psygnal \
    importlib-resources \
    msgpack \
    magicgui \
    et-xmlfile \
    ray \
    httplib2 \
    prometheus-client \
    mkl-fft \
    cachey \
    chart-studio \
    npe2 \
    jupyter-client \
    tinycss2 \
    oauth2client \
    service-identity \
    napari-svg \
    backports.shutil-get-terminal-size \
    jupyterlab-launcher \
    mkl-random \
    napari \
    google-apitools \
    jupyter-core \
    fastjsonschema \
    opencv-python \
    napari \ 
    'napari[all]' \ 
    'napari[pyside2]' \
    ray \
    scikit-image \
    zarr \
    nvidia-pyindex \
    nvidia-dali-cuda110

# install neuroglancer from github
RUN git clone https://github.com/google/neuroglancer.git
WORKDIR neuroglancer
RUN ls 
RUN python3 setup.py install

ADD docker_demo.py $HOME/docker_demo.py
ADD notebooks $HOME/notebooks
ADD test_data $HOME/test_data
USER root
RUN chown -R neuroglancer_user:neuroglancer_user $HOME/notebooks
RUN chown -R neuroglancer_user:neuroglancer_user $HOME/docker_demo.py

# Open ports for the notebook and the server
EXPOSE 8888
EXPOSE 8989

# run the notebook as a user
USER neuroglancer_user
WORKDIR $HOME
CMD jupyter notebook --ip='0.0.0.0'
```

Comment: Might be (I'm not very much in to debian administration) that adding an additional package source doesn't run an `apt-get update`, so when you try to install the latest nodejs version, it's in fact still refererring to the original package sources of debian, so try adding an additional `apt-get update` before executing `apt-get install -y nodejs`

Comment: OR you could just use `FROM node:19-bullseye` which will give you a baseimage of debian bullseye with node 19 preinstalled https://hub.docker.com/_/node

Comment: (...and then you can remove the Python parts to a separate image.)

Comment: thanks @derpirscher, changing the base image worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

You install node and npm in probably matching but old versions via `apt-get install -y npm`
Then you update npm to the latest available version which requires a more recent node-version via `npm install -g npm@latest`
if you just skip this line, it should work. BUT if you need more recent versions of node or npm this will not help you. Then you need to install node AND npm in another way, for example via nvm, but not via apt (or you use another repository, but the non-apt-way is better for situations lie this)

Comment: Yes you are correct. However, I did need a newer version so I could not just update to the latest as you mentioned. Thank you though! The response from derpirscher did the trick.